# How to send transactions using RPC?

Tags: rpc, transactions

I'm developing a client library for Dart. I wonder how can I send transactions using RPC.

If I wanted to send a balance transfer only using RPC how could I do it? What are the steps?

I know that I should encode the data before sending it, but I couldn't figure out what to encode and what RPC method to send.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To send the transaction look at the [author_submitExtrinsic](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#submitextrinsicextrinsic-extrinsic-hash) and [author_submitAndWatchExtrinsic](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#submitandwatchextrinsicextrinsic-extrinsic-extrinsicstatus), the latter when using subscriptions and wanting to have access to the processing status.

As to the format, it really depends on the on-chain metadata and the signed extensions that are applied on the extrinsic. However generally, assuming Polkadot/Kusama it would be in the following format -

- compact encoded length
- version + signing bit (as per metadata, currently `0x84` when signed - version 4, high bit indicates that is it signed)
- address of sender (generally MultiAddress, so 33 bytes in length)
- signature of [extrinsic payload](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2904/627) (generally MultiSignature type, so 65 bytes in length)
- mortal era
- nonce
- tip
- call (indexes and params)

Comment: `author_submitExtrinsic` is what I was looking for! Thanks to Dan I can see exact steps you mentioned in subxt https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/subxt/src/client.rs#L316

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate#mobile lists at least one option: https://github.com/Pocket4D/Polkadot-Dart

Although at the time I am writing it looks stale and unfinished, sadly. But it can perhaps give you a head start to build what you need. There are a few more here to review too https://github.com/search?q=dart+substrate .

The canonical way to submit transactions aka extrinsics is via the Polkadot.js API, one tool that you may reference for how to do this could be best exemplified in the [substrate-api-sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/8906816934b8e6bd5bf98393f83d55a6711d296e/src/services/transaction/TransactionSubmitService.ts#L28).

In rust there is also https://github.com/paritytech/subxt that is worth a look.

Hope these help!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a lack of Substrate libraries for the dart-lang. I'm planning to fill that void. Taking a look at `subxt` helped a lot.