# Extrinsic Struct

Tags: polkadot-js

Hey so I was running a local node and trying explorer/polkadot.js-scripts to submit some extrinsic and from what I have seen from the data log, I have seen that something is being appended before the original data. Like I have seen that its scale enocoded and the length of vector is there, but there's more to it! Not sure what all being inside the extrinsic struct.
I have got a struct from gsrpc [extrinsic struct](https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/blob/e00160ba0bd929b32b62a05a43a689d38d646ea9/types/extrinsic.go#L46). I don't know if this is what I'm looking for. So can I have some reference on what struct of extrinsic is being used in polkadot-js or what is being added to the original data.

Comment: Could be double scale encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a previous [answer with a full breakdown](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2933/627) of an extrinsic.

Additionally you can also paste encoded data into the apps UI, and decode it into the parts to see what goes where (encoding details pane on the bottom right). Here is an example [of a recent transfer](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode/0x4102840012a0c156613317ad2693d5e8803d9f2876aedf664a854839aee08e4d7d4e54e30062a35b6de0416283ef97940d66421a2d0a7cde23acaaea3e12517f6dc402c2a435e5dc2b333203f0afb22aaae9bdba9f85f7406983c8778525911fe6ab3f9d0a26000000050300fc2bd36384a182977a5c888bb06039fa9af413399a35345b4222dd53046aed4107c0b4532526) on Polkadot.